# Vagrant, VirtualBox, Capistrano, db:migrate - could not connect to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, vagrant, dbmigrate

I have just worked my way through the book "Deploying Rails" and im stuck where capaistrano calls db:migrate.

I have set up two VMs  - app und db - each of them separate working perfektly.
The VM app ist hostin nginx/unicorn and the VM db ist hosting PostgreSQL.
I can "vagrant ssh" into the VMs and every thing looks good.

This is my Vagrant file with the two VMs defined (I'm using Vagrant version 1.0.3):

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|

  config.vm.define :app do |app_config|
    app_config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "app", "--memory", "512"]
    app_config.vm.box = "lucid64_rb193_pp2719"
    app_config.vm.host_name = "app"
    app_config.vm.forward_port 22, 2200, :auto => true
    app_config.vm.forward_port 80, 8080
    app_config.vm.network :hostonly, "33.33.13.37"
    app_config.vm.share_folder "puppet", "/etc/puppet", "../log4job_ops"
  end

  config.vm.define :db do |db_config|
    db_config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "db", "--memory", "512"]
        db_config.vm.box = "lucid64_rb193_pp2719"
        db_config.vm.host_name = "db"
        db_config.vm.forward_port 22, 2201, :auto => true
        db_config.vm.forward_port 5432, 5432
        db_config.vm.network :hostonly, "33.33.13.38"
        db_config.vm.share_folder "puppet", "/etc/puppet", "../log4job_ops"
  end
end
```

As you can see, data sent to port 8080 is forwarded to port 80 an tghe app VM and that works very well.

As PostgreSQL listens to port 5432 i set up a port forwarding of 4532(Host)->4532(VM).

However, when running either "cap deploy:cold" or "cap deploy:migrate" it get this Error message (cap deploy:migrate):

```
  * executing `deploy:migrate'
  * executing "ls -x /var/log4job/releases"
    servers: ["localhost"]
    [localhost] executing command
    command finished in 37ms
  * executing "cd /var/log4job/releases/20120905140228 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
    servers: ["localhost"]
    [localhost] executing command
*** [err :: localhost] rake aborted!
*** [err :: localhost] could not connect to server: Connection refused
*** [err :: localhost] Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
*** [err :: localhost] TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
*** [err :: localhost] could not connect to server: Connection refused
*** [err :: localhost] Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
*** [err :: localhost] TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
*** [err :: localhost] 
*** [err :: localhost] Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
*** [err :: localhost] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished in 4128ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /var/log4job/releases/20120905140228 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate'" on localhost
```

Questions:

1. What am i doing wrong?
2. Is the "rake db:migrate" command running on the VM "app".
   I assume that, as the project source code is deployed to /var/log4job/releases/20120905140228
3. If my assumtion at nr 2 above is correct, its no wonder that its not working. PostgreSQL is running on the VM "db". But how on earth do you set upp this type of service?
   Have i configured the database connection in database.yml wrong.

This is the production part of the database.yml:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  template: template0
  username: log4jobuid
  password: log4jobpwd
  database: wl_prod
  host: localhost
  encoding: unicode
  port: 5432
```

Shure. It says it should listen to "localhost" ;-) but how do i configure it, to connect into the other VM (the "db" VM)?

Any hints are welcome!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it!

The best way to find an answer, is to write down the question ;-)

The errors that I have made wre all in the database.yml

It should look like this:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  template: template0
  username: log4jobuid
  password: log4jobpwd
  database: wl_prod
  host: 33.33.13.38
  encoding: unicode
  port: 5432
```

The IP-Adress for "host:" should be the IP-Adress stated in the Vagrant file for the DB VM:

```
db_config.vm.network :hostonly, "33.33.13.38"
```

Now we know, that you can connect from e.g. one VM "app" into another VM "db" using the IP-Adress of the VM.

You should also make shure, you state the correct database name, user and password for the database. In my case, i let puppet create the db, so i use the same settings on both sides (now ;-)